# Call a controller scope function from directive in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a scope function inside controller, I need to trigger it from directive , the directive is a dropdown, so whenever i am changing the value i need to trigger a function from directive to controller.

**HTML**

```
<dropdown-single-select filter-params=false eventlstn="selectTab('summary')" api-params="serviceApiParams"  select-options="filterData.classFilter" selected-value="filterData.selectedClassOptions" ></dropdown-single-select>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('dropdownSingleSelect',['$document', function($document){
    return {
        scope: {
          onSelect: '&',          
          selectOptions: '=',
          isoFilterParams:'=filterParams',
          isoEventListener:'=eventListener',
          selectedValue:'=',
          defaultOption:'=',
          disable:'&',
          apiParams:'='       
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'commonActions/waggle-single-select.tpl.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {          

            scope.toggleOptions= function(){
                scope.showOptions = !scope.showOptions;
            }
            scope.selectOption = function(option){               

                if(scope.apiParams.reload){
                    scope.apiParams.classViewId=option.classViewId;
                    scope.$apply(attr.eventlstn);
                }            
        }
    };
}])
```

**controller**

```
.controller('studentSummaryReportCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope){

$scope.selectTab=function(data){
console.log(data);
}

}])
```

dropdown is working fine and also the selectoption is working fine but when it comes to *scope.$apply(attr.eventlstn);* it is not working

Comment: You could pass the method to the directive with '&' and just call it from the directive link function like this `scope.selectTab('summary')`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i tried calling function with $emit and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

add  eventlstn : '&' and then call when needed scope.$apply(scope.eventLstn(args))

Answer (score 0):

You can call the controller function from the directive link function
as your directive is an "Element Type" (E) you have to add attribute which you have added as `eventlstn="selectTab(summary)"` in directive the change you have to do is below

```
return {
        scope: {
          onSelect: '&', 
          eventlstn: '&',         
          selectOptions: '=',
          isoFilterParams:'=filterParams',
          isoEventListener:'=eventListener',
          selectedValue:'=',
          defaultOption:'=',
          disable:'&',
          apiParams:'='       
        },
```

So I have added as 2nd param of scope variable the parameter which you are sending to controller form selectTab function is summary So how to pass the value to summary so that it will call the controller function is below

Just for example think you need to pass the value of option to summary of select tab which you controller function will catch as data you need to use same key what you used in directive attribute as object key.

```
scope.selectOption = function(option) {
    scope.eventlstn({
        summary: option
    })
};
```